# Android GUI gets hanged during registration on berkeke server

Tags: java, android

I have written a code which involves media transmission between android device and a sip based phone.It works well for audio transmission.Further,I want to register the device on berkeke server but after 8seconds of launching,application gets hanged(device successfully got registered). I am unable to find whether the problem is with GUI or registration process.Earlier,before registration,it works for 90 seconds and then gets hanged.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of threading to handle the transactions separate from the UI thread? Always keep two things in mind:
Do not block the UI thread, and
Make sure that you access the Android UI toolkit only on the UI thread.
[Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use async calls, I think your registration is making a blocking call.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

For CPU intense tasks and network related tasks make use of the Async Tasks else your UI gets hanged you will get an ANR (Application Not Responding) error.